# Google Public API access, Allowed Referrers Key for browser applications

Tags: google-api

I'm using a Key for browser applications. I'm trying to set a domain Referrers so it is only functional on my website but the API stop working.

example: 
the api is on www.mywebsite.com/v1.html
I've tried *.mywebsite.com/* on the Edit allowed Referrers page and it stop working